# $injector get method is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have upgraded AngularJS from 1.5.9 to 1.6.1
Now the command: $injector.get('myOtherService') results in this exception:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'get'
```

What do I need to do so $injector has a get method?

Comment: can you show more code?  It would seem that you aren't instantiating `$injector` correctly.

Comment: Where is it being called from? Perhaps it should be this.$injector.get() ?

Answer (score 0):

Claies was right my code was in error,